# Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent

Tags: powershell

I'm using `PowerShell` Ver. `5.1.14393.2248`
My script is located in the path: `C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules\PSScriptVersionChecker`.

I want to get the parent path like: `C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules`.
When I run:

```
$destination = Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent
$destination
```

I'll still get `C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules\PSScriptVersionChecker` instead of `C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should **check the output of $PSCommandPath** when running the script. It probably don't point to `C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules\PSScriptVersionChecker` since when you invoke:

`Split-Path C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules\PSScriptVersionChecker`

You will get `C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules`.

Comment: Martin, you are right, means: using $PSCommandPath is the wrong aproach.
Having my script in: C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules\PSScriptVersionChecker\test.ps1, $PSCommandPath gets me: C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules\PSScriptVersionChecker\test.ps1 and because of that using Split-Path results in C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules\PSScriptVersionChecker and not in (as desired): C:\Anwendungen\PowershellAddOn\Modules.
A better Approach is to use: get-Location (probably)
thanks

Comment: I am  using `$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition`

Answer (score 1):

Read [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables):

> ```
> $PSCommandPath
>    Contains the full path and file name of the script that is being run. 
>    This variable is valid in all scripts.
> …
>
> $PSScriptRoot
>    Contains the directory from which a script is being run. 
>
>    In Windows PowerShell 2.0, this variable is valid only in script modules
>    (.psm1). Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, it is valid in all scripts.
> ```

Use:

```
$destination = Split-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent) -Parent
```

or, in Windows PowerShell 3.0 and above:

```
$destination = Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent
```

Comment: thanks Josef, in the meantime I noticed my fault...one doesn't dare to understimate the reading and understanding the PowerShell-Help :-)
thanks